# Is there a way to make `lm` report the amount of observations used (instead of omitted)?

Tags: r, lm

Simple question. I would like to immediately get the amount of observations used by the `lm` model when I subset the data. But just to give a reproducible example:

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread(
  "ID   DEP   C  fac  H   I   clvl   iso   year   matchcode
     1   1   1   NA   9   1    1     NLD   2009   NLD2009
     2   1   1   NA   8   1    1     NLD   2009   NLD2009
     3   7   0   NA   3   0    2     NLD   2014   NLD2014
     4   8   0   NA   4   0    2     NLD   2014   NLD2014
     5   1   0   B    6   0    2     AUS   2011   AUS2011
     6   2   0   B    7   0    2     AUS   2011   AUS2011
     7   4   1   B    8   1    2     AUS   2007   AUS2007
     8   5   1   B    7   7    2     AUS   2007   AUS2007
     9   6   0   NA   5   1    1     USA   2007   USA2007
     10  1   0   NA   5   1    1     USA   2007   USA2007
     11  0   1   NA   0   0    2     USA   2011   USA2010
     12  2   1   NA   1   0    2     USA   2011   USA2010
     13  2   0   NA   6   NA   3     USA   2013   USA2013
     14  9   0   NA   4   0    3     USA   2013   USA2013
     15  8   1   A    5   1    2     BLG   2007   BLG2007
     16  2   0   A    6   0    4     BEL   2009   BEL2009
     17  NA  0   A    1   0    4     BEL   2009   BEL2009
     18  9   1   A    0   1    4     BEL   2012   BEL2012",
  header = TRUE
)

ols <- lm(DEP ~ H + I + iso, data=df, subset=(ID != 15))
summary(ols)
```

Is there a way to make `lm` report the amount of observations used (instead of omitted)? I can seriously not find this anywhere. It is important because I not know the amount of observations of each subset by heart.

```
   Call:
lm(formula = DEP ~ H + I + iso, data = df, subset = (ID != 15))

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-4.930 -1.907 -0.167  1.855  6.065 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)    5.658      3.589    1.58     0.15
H             -0.499      0.436   -1.14     0.28
I              0.417      0.594    0.70     0.50
isoBEL         1.130      3.592    0.31     0.76
isoNLD         1.376      2.685    0.51     0.62
isoUSA        -0.728      3.030   -0.24     0.82

Residual standard error: 3.6 on 9 degrees of freedom
  (2 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.206, Adjusted R-squared:  -0.235 
F-statistic: 0.468 on 5 and 9 DF,  p-value: 0.791
```

If not, what would be the easiest way to deduce it from the `lm` output?

Comment: perhaps `length(ols$residuals)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `nobs()` function tells you how many observations were used

```
nobs(ols)
```